# SARIMAX.predict() and SARIMAX.forecast() exog? Does exog need to be preknown for predict()?

Tags: python, forecasting, arima, statsmodels

On `SARIMAX.predict`, when you have an exog but the exog is only known today and in the past, how do you predict the endog's next 12 months off just the exog and data known through today?  Is that what the `SARIMAX.predict` is doing as a default?  Example, my exog is SP500 price.  I do not know what it will be tomorrow, but I want to use the values through today as an exog to predict the next 12 months forward of my endog.

Or is `SARIMAX.predict` wanting you to know what the future exog values will be for the 12 months into the future of the endog you are predicting?  Example, my exog is days  of the week.  I know today what day of the week things will happen on so I can fill in the future exog for the next 12 months to predict the endog for the same forward period.

If as in the first example of SP500 exog where the exog is not known in the future, is `SARIMAX.forecast(steps = forecast_periods, exog = exog[-forecast_periods:])` giving a 1 step ahead 12 month forecast? Or is it in this case falsely assuming the exog I populated is a 12 month future exog that is known today?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you set up your model. To take a very special case of zero-mean ARX(1), it can be
$$
y_t=\varphi_1 y_{t-1}+\beta x_t+u_t
$$
or
$$
y_t=\varphi_1 y_{t-1}+\beta x_{t-1}+v_t.
$$
In the former case, you need the $x$ value that is contemporaneous with the $y$ value for forecasting. In the latter case you need the $x$ value that is lagged with respect to the $y$ value for forecasting. Depending on how your model is set up, you would estimate it differently, too. You would either use contemporaneous $x$s (in the former setup) or lagged $x$s (in the latter setup) in estimation.

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer.  I think my confusion is in what SARIMAX.forecast() is actually doing.  My assumption was that it is was running a general SARIMA (no exog) as one would expect, and then layering over the regressions of exog variables.  Based on the forecast horizon passed, it would then make a forward forecast of that entire horizon as of the date that pulls through each iteration.  Example, Jan'23 with a 12 mo forecast, I use the SARIMA from previous time + Jan'23's exog values to predict Feb'23 - Jan'24.  It appears that is not the case.  If not, is there a way to do this?

Comment: To clarify the end goal would really be to get SARIMAX to generate a forecast of the next 12 months based on what is known today.  The issue I am running into is the exog needed in the .forecast() is SARIMAX.forecast( steps = 12, exog = exog[-12:]), but those exog's are not known today so I cannot put in a future 12 months of exogs.  

However, all I want is a 1 time 12 month forecast based off today's known (or the last known) exog's and past SARIMA results of the endog.  I am not sure if that is possible.  Many thanks!

Comment: @Lee, sorry, I do not use Python, so I will not get into the details of that. Perhaps someone else can post a more relevant answer.

Comment: No problem.  I think I found an answer.   The ARIMAX and SARIMAX based models are all 1-step (rolling and building on the previous forecast for as many iterations as it takes to reach the end of the forecast_horizon) vs multistep which is a single 1 time estimate of the entire forecast_horizon.  It sounds like as it stands, the models do not have the capability to run multistep which is what your equations demonstrate and was kind of my hunch.  Sounds like several open source places are working on development of multistep ARIMA based modeling.  Who knew haha